Exercise 1, Section 5.3 of Hungerford’s Algebra
Definition: Let $S$ be a set of polynomials of positive degree in $K[x]$. An extension field $F$ of $K$ is said to be a splitting field over $K$ of the set $S$ of polynomials if every polynomial in $S$ splits in $F[x]$ and $F$ is generated over $K$ by the roots of all the polynomials in $S$.

Question: Prove of the following theorem

$F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of a finite set $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ of polynomials in $K[x]$ if and only if $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of the single polynomial $f=f_1\cdots f_n$.

Below I have written proof of above exercise. It is quite important result. We only care about splitting field of set $S$ of polynomials when $S$ is either single polynomial or infinite.
Here is another proof of above exercise using induction method. In my opinion, that proof don’t have adequate details.

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of $f_1,…,f_n \in K[x]$. Then each $f_i$ split over $F$. That is $f_i=u_{0i}(x-u_{1i})\cdots (x-u_{k_ii})$ where $u_{ji}\in F$. So
$$f=f_1\cdots f_n= u_{01}\cdots u_{0n} (x-u_{11})\cdots (x-u_{k_11})\cdots (x-u_{1n})\cdots (x-u_{k_nn})$$
Thus $f$ split over $F$. By hypothesis, $F=K(X)$ where $X$ is set of all roots of $f_1,…,f_n$. Let $Y$ be set of all roots of $f$. It is easy to see, $X =\{u_{ji}\in F \mid 1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq k_i\}=Y$. Hence $F=K(X)=K(Y)$. Therefore $F$ is splitting field over $K$ of $f$.
($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of $f=f_1\cdots f_n\in K[x]$. Then $f$ split over $F$. That is
$$f=f_1\cdots f_n=u_0 \prod_{ji} (x-u_{ji})$$
where $u_{ij}\in F$ and $ji \in \text{finite indexing set}$. Since $F[x]$ is unique factorization domain and $f_i\in F[x]$, we have $f_i=v_ig_{1i}\cdots g_{k_ii}$ where $v_i$ is unit in $F$ and $g_{ji}$ are irreducible elements of $F[x]$. Note $(x-u_i)$ are irreducible elements of $F[x]$, since it can not be written as product of two non-unit (or equivalently non constant) polynomials in $F[x]$. By definition of UFD, each $g_{ji}$ is associate to $(x-u_{ji})$. So $g_{ji}=r_{ji}(x-u_{ji})$ where $r_{ji}$ is unit in $F$. Thus $f_i = v_ir_{1i}\cdots r_{k_ii}(x-u_{1i})\cdots (x-u_{k_ii})$ split over $F$.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be set of all roots of $f_1,…,f_n$ and $f$, respectively. Then $X=\{u_{ji}\mid 1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq k_i\}=Y$. Thus $F=K(X)=K(Y)$. Hence $F$ is splitting field over $K$ of $f_1,…,f_n$.
